# Must a matrix be symmetric if Row Space = Column Space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrix which the Row Space=Column Space, and I need to prove that the matrix is symmetric.

I need your help please!

Comment: If it was true, all nonsingular matrices would be symmetric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is true. Consider the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$.

The row space and the column space is $\mathbb{R}^2$, but the matrix is not symmetric.